# Katalon test stuck on "Running"

Tags: google-chrome, testing, katalon-studio

Katalon test running stuck on Running with all the browser options

[Katalon stuck on running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrjie.png)

Any clue on how to solve this?

I am using a simple open browser script

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Chrome version and ChromeDriver version are incompatible. Refer to this page on how to update ChromeDriver in Katalon Studio: https://docs.katalon.com/display/KD/Update+or+Replace+Web+Browser+Drivers+and+Selenium

Answer (score 0):

If it's stuck, there are solutions.

1. Close katalon and re-run it.
2. Open the 'Task Manager' and delete chrome driver from background process.
3. Update chromedriver.exe file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any Katalon profiles, please change those from defaults

Ex  : [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Katalone studio then all you have to do is you have to close the Chrome browser on which the script is being run by the Katalone studio and it will start working from where stopped.